# Problem integrating AdMob with android app

Tags: java, android

I am trying to integrate AdMob banner adds with my android app.  I have followed instructions at https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml to the letter.
I have put my APPLICATION_ID in the meta-data in my Manifest file and using the Google supplied Add unit ID for testing, which is
"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111".  I keep getting the following error:
Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException
The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers

I have hunted the internet and can't find the problem.

Manifest.xml

```
<application
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.adds.APPLIATION_ID"
    android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxxxx" />
  <activity
    ....
  </activity>
</application>
```

In build.gradle I have:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lornalaycock.retirementsimulator"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 10
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel 'SYMBOL_TABLE'
            }
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    ndkVersion "23.0.7599858"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues=true;
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.1.0-beta.1'
    implementation 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.1.0'
    implementation 'mk.webfactory.dz:maskededittext:2.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.3.0'
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha02"
    implementation 'androidx.wear:wear:1.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.3.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2.1"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}
        maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}
        maven {url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In the xml file:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

In MainActivity

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });


        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Any ideas, please help.  Tearing my hair out.

After nearly all day messing with different ideas I still have a problem. I removed all code relating to the AdMob stuff and created a new project with nothing but Hello World Text View.  I then added the following line to the build.gradle.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.3.0'
```

synching and the running Hello World I get the following error, which is the same error I get when trying to test my original app.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.admobtest, PID: 27348
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
    * should follow the instructions here:                                       *
    * https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
```

In the project build.gradle I added mavenCentral() under allprojects.

In the Manifest file I added:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

But it seems the line to include the dependency is causing the crash.
Am I missing something?

Comment: add `mavenCentral()` in `buildscript` and `allprojects` in your project level gradle

Comment: I added mavenCentral() to my build script and remove d jcenter() as it is deprecated.  But then I could not import any packages from github which my app depends on.  I had to leave jcenter() in there.  I updated to the lastest Android Studio 2020.3.1 and the latest gradle tools 7.0.1 but still have the problem.

Comment: have to tried keeping `jcenter()` and `mavenCentral()` ?

Comment: Yes, I put both jcenter() and mavenCentral() in build.gradle but still have same problem.  Two days now spent on this.  Can"t give up.  Must find solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this working, but not exactly sure why.  What I did was download latest version of Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 1, and gradle Version 7.0.2 with plugin 7.0.1.  I then created a brand new project from scratch and imported my code from the previous project using subversion.  I did not import the build.gradle files or the AndroidManifest but left these as they were in the newly created project. I then modified these according to the tutorial on the web https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start .  I added all my dependencies for my project into the app build.gradle and presto, IT WORKED!
I used the google test id for APPLICATION_ID and the adUnitId in the .xml.
But, when I changed the APPLIATOIN_ID in the Manifest to my real one, but left the adUnitId as the test one, then I suddenly got that error again :
Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider:
So, it seems in testing you must use both the test IDs and not a mix of your real APPLICATION_ID and the test adUnitId.

Not sure yet what I am supposed to have in the code when I create an internal release for testing.  I will leave the testing ids and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

One more important thing I forgot to mention.  After creating the new project with empty activity in Android Studio I had to modify the settingd.gradle as follows:

```
//dependencyResolutionManagement {
//    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
//    repositories {
//        google()
//        mavenCentral()
//        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
//    }
//}
rootProject.name = "TuesdayTest"
include ':app'
```

Had to comment out these lines that were in my project level build.gradle.  I found this from a problem someone else had.  Seems to be an issue with all the latest builds and dependencies in Android Studio and google() and mavenCentral().  Also I still had to lave jcenter() in the files to be able to import packages from GitHub.  I think Google has gotten things into a bit of a mess.